# Prove nth derivative of $(1+x)^x$ is divided by n

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I stuck with my solution.

$f(x) = (1+x)^x$

Needed to prove that function's $n$th derivative is divided by $n$ in $0$.

$n \mid  f^{(n)}(0) $

$(1+x)^x = \sum_{i=0}^x \binom {x} {i}$

If $n > x$ that's ok. We get $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ cause derivative of sum is sum of derivatives and each member of sum of derivatives $= 0$ (in $x = 0$).

If $n \le x$ we can find just one summand which does not turn into $0$. This number has form of $\binom {x} {n}x^n$

Let $\binom {x} {n} =  \alpha$ So $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$

And we should prove that $(\alpha x^n)^{(n)}$ is divided by n; I suggest that $(\alpha x ^n)^{(n)} = \alpha n (n-1) (n-2) \cdots 2x$ and it's of course is divided by n. But I checked my suggest in wolfram and wolfram told me I'm wrong. Could you help me find my fault?

Comment: what is the first derivative?

Comment: With the zero $x$ we have interest just in $x^1$ which have coefficient $\binom {x} {1}$ so derivative of it is 1. $\binom {0} {any} = 1$ as I remember. At total derivative in $x = 0$ is 1 and 1 is divided by 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $(1+x)^x = \sum_{i=0}^x \binom {x} {i}$

Sorry, but no. That is for positive integer powers, but $x$ is not an integer in general. And it varies, so you have to differentiate with respect to the exponent too.

One way to handle this is to take the logarithm and use implicit differentation:

$$\begin{align}\frac {d}{dx}\ln f(x) &= \frac {d}{dx}(x\ln(1+x))\\
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} &= \ln(1 + x) + \frac{x}{1+x}\\
f'(x) &= f(x)\left(\ln(1 + x) + \frac{x}{1+x}\right)\\
f'(x) &= (1+x)^x\ln(1+x) + x(1+x)^{x-1}
\end{align}$$

As you can guess, the higher powers get worse. You'll need to figure out the pattern to them, and use induction to prove your result.